# Simple question about changing the place of x and y in an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'd like to change the place of $x$ with $y$ in my equation to get a new equation for which I give $y$ as the input and at the end, the result be the $x$.

The current equation is:

$$y\:=\:5.46339\:+\:\frac{63.10168-5.46339}{1\:+\:10^{\:0.35141\left(15.18895-x\right)}}$$

Thank you.

Comment: What you want to do is called solving the equation for $x$. Have you tried manipulating the given equation to move operations to the $y$ side? After the first step, you should have $y-5.46339=...$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y\:=5.46339+\frac{63.10168-5.46339}{1+10^{\:0.35141\left(15.18895-x\right)}}$$
$$y\:-5.46339=\frac{63.10168-5.46339}{1+10^{\:0.35141\left(15.18895-x\right)}}$$
$$1+10^{\:0.35141\left(15.18895-x\right)}=\frac{63.10168-5.46339}{y\:-5.46339}$$
$$10^{\:0.35141\left(15.18895-x\right)}=\frac{63.10168-5.46339}{y\:-5.46339}-1$$
$$0.35141\left(15.18895-x\right)=\log _{10}\left(\frac{63.10168-5.46339}{y\:-5.46339}-1\right)$$
$$\left(15.18895-x\right)=\frac{\log _{10}\left(\frac{63.10168-5.46339}{y\:-5.46339}-1\right)}{0.35141}$$
$$x=15.18895-\frac{\log _{10}\left(\frac{63.10168-5.46339}{y\:-5.46339}-1\right)}{0.35141}$$
$$x=15.18895-\frac{\log _{10}\left(\frac{57.63829}{y\:-5.46339}-1\right)}{0.35141},y\ne 5.46339$$